# Append image with php

Tags: php, wordpress, lazy-loading

I'm working with a plugin that lazy loads images http://wordpress.org/plugins/unveil-lazy-load/

```
  if(is_feed() || is_preview() || self::is_smartphone())  return $content;

  if ( strpos( $content, 'data-src' ) !== false )
    return $content;

    $dummy_image = self::get_url('b.gif');

    $content = preg_replace( '#<img([^>]+?)src=[\'"]?([^\'"\s>]+)[\'"]?([^>]*)>#', sprintf( '<img${1}src="%s" data-src="${2}"${3}><noscript><img${1}src="${2}"${3}></noscript>', $dummy_image ), $content );

    return $content;
}
```

From what I gather, this is checking to see if content 'data-src' exists and if it hasn't loaded, it appends the source with 'b.gif' until the data loads then lazy loads the image.

Using this line:

```
 $dummy_image = self::get_url('b.gif');
```

I'm looking to append the image with and actual  so I can add a class to a preloaded image instead.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here: what do you want to append to what? If by "add a class" you mean a CSS class, that doesn't sound like appending anything to me, but altering the attributes in the HTML tag...

Comment: I want to append or (replace) the image itself with it's own img tag basically.

Comment: You can see on this page, the image is being replaced with a tiled image upon lazy load. I'd like to use an animated ajax like loader instead but the image is set to a specific embeded size so if I use an ajax .gif loading image, it expands to the full width of the placeholder.  http://joelechelberger.com/headshots-studio-headshots-by-joel-echelberger-photography/amy-smith-actress-headshots/

Comment: It's not a tiled image, it's just a uniform colour so that it can be stretched to any size without looking freaky. This is the central trick of this "lazy-loader": it is just changing the `src` attribute of the image rather than needing more complex HTML manipulation. If you want a tiled or centered image, you'll need to change the way the JS works so that you can have a placeholder `<div>` that you can set the background for.